# ArgumentException when assigning a resource to CustomMessageBox.Content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app using the Windows Phone Toolkit.
When working with the CustomMessageBox provided by this extension, you have to set the Content property to whatever you want this control to display.
When I set the Content to a StackPanel created in code it works ok. However, when I create a StackPanel in XAML, in the Application.Resources like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Key="MessageBox">
        <TextBlock Text="Teste"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Application.Resources>
```

And assign it to the CustomMessageBox

```
var messageBox = new CustomMessageBox();
messageBox.Content = Application.Current.Resources["MessageBox"];
```

It throws an ArgumentException telling me that "Value does not fall within the expected range".

When I wrap this StackPanel into another StackPanel, created in code like this:

```
var sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add(Application.Current.Resources["MessageBox"];
```

This time it throws an InvalidOperationException saying that "Element is already the child of another element".

So I suppose I'm declaring an application resource in XAML the wrong way!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.  It's ContentTemplate.

XAML

---

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PivotApp1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageBoxTemp">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Teste"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

C#

---

```
messageBox.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["MessageBoxTemp"];
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I wonder why it doesn't work the way I did. Thanks for your help.